# Get if field has max value and display value

Tags: oracle, query

I need to display Y or N when displaying rows in a report based on the max value for them on their version. If they have multiple versions all of them will display 'N' but the max (last version) will display 'Y'.

I have tried with case when and max but always I'm getting 'Y'

```
case when version = (select max(version) from t_proj_f where version = t.version) then 'Y' else 'N' end Is_last_version
```

Here is fiddle in case anybody can take a look
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/813501/4

I'm new on oracle sql any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analysis

Your inner SQL statement is always TRUE (for non-null values).
You are probably wanting the `max(version)` for each `project_id`, not each `version`.

Additionally, these scalar sub-queries are known to be slow at times.

## Solution

Use an Analytical function.

## PLAN vs

Yours, right side, is doing two Full Table Scans vs my one.  This becomes worse with larger tables.
[image]

## Code

```sql
select t.project_id,
  t.version,
  t.stp,
  t.t_id,
  t.status,
  t.mp,
  case
    when t.version = max(t.version) over (partition by t.project_id)
    then 'Y'
    else 'N'
   end Is_last_version
from t_proj_f t
```

**code review note:** always use the appropriate table alias on ALL columns, especially if the column could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will give you want you want:

```
 select project_id,
        version,
        stop,
        t_id,
        status,
        mp,
        case when rowno = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end is_last_version
        from (
              select project_id,
                     version,
                     stop,
                     t_id,
                     status,
                     mp,
                     row_number() over (partition by projecT_id order by version desc) 
                        as rowno
              from t_proj_f t
              order by project_id)
```